# IntelliSense gives a Class icon to a function

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm using **Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate**, the code below is written in Vb.Net.

The problem I have is that **IntelliSense** gives **[the icon of a Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx)** to a function:

[image]

I would like to know what can be causing this behavior, if its a bug, or an issue with my code.

This is the code:

```vb
Public NotInheritable Class ProcessUtil

    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Performs a WMI query to Win32_Process class with the specified condition and returns the result.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' This is useful for example to get information of a 64-Bit process from a 32-Bit .Net assembly.
    ''' </remarks>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <example> This is a code example.
    ''' <code>
    ''' Dim condition As New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("Name", "notepad.exe")
    ''' 
    ''' For Each mo As ManagementObject In ProcessUtil.GetWmiProcessQuery(condition)
    ''' 
    '''     MessageBox.Show(DirectCast(mo.Properties("ExecutablePath").Value, String))
    ''' 
    ''' Next mo
    ''' </code>
    ''' </example>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <param name="condition">
    ''' The WHERE condition to use in the SELECT query.
    ''' </param>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <returns>
    ''' The query result.
    ''' </returns>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Shared Function GetWmiProcessQuery(ByVal condition As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) As ManagementObject()

        Dim scope As New ManagementScope("root\CIMV2")
        Dim query As New SelectQuery(String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process Where {0} = '{1}'", condition.Key, condition.Value))
        Dim options As New EnumerationOptions With {.ReturnImmediately = True}

        Using wmi As New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query, options)

            Using objCol As ManagementObjectCollection = wmi.Get

                Return objCol.Cast(Of ManagementObject).ToArray

            End Using

        End Using

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: If you hover over it, does it call it a class?

Comment: @DangerZone No, it call it a Function in the InteliSense's tooltip, however it shows a class icon.

Comment: That's interesting... Just seems like a bug then. As long as it's working as expected... Have you tried cleaning the solution, restarting visual studio and rebuilding?

Comment: @DangerZone I found what was causing this annonying behavior, the function is contained in a dll which is part of an API so I just loaded the dll in a new peoject to test, but as the function uses WMI it needs to reference the SystemManagement assembly, so once referenced the icon dissapeared. Maybe was a bug or maybe a kind of icon-advice (to denote the lack of needed reference to use the function). thanks for comment. I will make a new question about this to require that dll referenced in any project which referenced my dll.